# Is there a dummy package like Lipsum or Blindtext for Tables and Figures?

Tags: tables, floats

Lipsum and Blindtext offer paragraphs, lists, and even whole documents of dummy content for testing LaTeX layouts.

Is there a package that will generate tables and figures in a similar way?

Comment: With package `MWE` you can use some dummy figures, but you have to include them by yourself.  Tables can be very difficult, best would be to include one that fit your needs (so written by you?)? In the manual of package `blindtext` you can read the reasons for the author not to include this functionality to `blindtext`.

Comment: Thank you for the introduction to `MWE`. I like `blindtext` a lot, but these particular _reasons_ don't elucidate much: 

`Tabulars need there own layout, I don’t think you may define a table for each use in blindtext.`

`I don’t think you may define a picture for each use in blindtext.`

Is this a technical boundary? (Does LaTeX **prevent** dummy tables and figures?)

Comment: if you use the `[draft]` option to the document class, any real figure will be rendered as just a frame of the appropriate size with the name of the referenced figure set in the middle for information.  or, within the `figure` environment, you could set a frame of the desired size instead of using `\includegraphics`.  tables are more complicated.

Comment: FWIW, in ConTeXt you can use: `\usemodule[visual] \starttext \simplethesis \stoptext` to get a thesis sized document consisting of randomized boxes (representing words) and just randomized square boxes for figures. The visual module also provides other useful commands for testing layouts, including randomized formulas, and figures (but no tables).

Comment: For that matter, you can use \includegraphics in a table or put a tabular into a figure.  About the only difference is the caption (and the queu).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how much this adds to the world, but here you go.

The package provides a dummy figure and a dummy table in float environments. The table will always equal the `\linewidth` so you can use it in different page geometries, as in the `twocolumn` example below. The figure is really a table, but this didn't seem like a problem if the main concern was to check caption formats and page layout.

I'd like to make this configurable (specify the float position, number of table rows, different figure widths, etc.) but I'll leave that to others if they need more than this provides.

---

Package `sator.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{sator}[2014/11/26 Dummy figures and tables for testing, by Andrew A. Cashner, cashner@uchicago.edu]

\RequirePackage{tabulary,booktabs}

\newcommand{\sator}{Sator arepo tenet opera rotas}
\newcommand{\Sator}{Sator Arepo Tenet Opera Rotas}

% For float labels
\newcounter{fignum}
\newcounter{tabnum}

% Figures
\newcommand{\satorfig}{%
    \stepcounter{fignum}%
    See figure~\ref{fig:\thefignum}.\par
    \begin{figure}
    {\huge\bfseries\hfil%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
        S & A & T & O & R\\ \hline
        A & R & E & P & O\\ \hline
        T & E & N & E & T\\ \hline
        O & P & E & R & A\\ \hline
        R & O & T & A & S\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}

    \caption{\sator}
    \label{fig:\thefignum}
    \end{figure}
}

%*******************
% Tables
\newcommand{\tableheader}{No. & Sator Arepo & Tenet Opera & Rotas\\}
\newcommand{\tablerow}[1]{#1 & \sator &  \sator & \sator\\}

\newcommand{\satortab}{%
    \stepcounter{tabnum}%
    See table~\ref{table:\thetabnum}.\par
    \begin{table}
        \caption{\sator}
        \label{table:\thetabnum}

        \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{rLLL}
            \toprule
            \tableheader\midrule
            \tablerow{1}
            \tablerow{2}
            \tablerow{3}
            \tablerow{4}
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabulary}
    \end{table}%
}

\endinput
```

---

Example use:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{sator}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{\Sator}
\lipsum[1-3]

\satorfig

\lipsum[4]

\subsection{\Sator}
\lipsum[5-7]

\satortab

\lipsum[8-9]
\satorfig
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The packages [todonotes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) and [luatodonotes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luatodonotes) offer `\missingfigure`:

[image: todonotes-missingfigure]

The package [mwe](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) provides the image "example-image", which can be included using `includegraphics{example-image}`. It also offers more images, such as one with a golden ratio etc.

[image: example-image]

I checked [easy-todo](https://ctan.org/pkg/easy-todo), [fixmetodonotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/fixmetodonotes), [todo](https://ctan.org/pkg/todo), and [fixme](https://ctan.org/pkg/fixme). All of them don't support easy specification of a missing figure.