# One sentence of dummy text

Tags: lipsum

I need to create just a specified number of sentences of dummy text (rather than a long paragraph). Can I use `lipsum` to do this? If not, then what can I use? The idea is to be able to create a MWE that doesn't contain a lot of distracting text in the source code, but allows me to use smaller numbers of sentences than I can get with `\lipsum[n]`.

Comment: Then what? What do you mean? If you need a more specific amount than `lipsum` or `blindtext` or `kantlipsum` provide, you can just write arbitrary text or copy the relevant amount of text from those packages.

Comment: you can use your `\mylipsum` command: `\newcommand{\mylipsum}{just dummy text}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can defines  command `\mylipsum`

```
\newcommand{\mylipsum}{just dummy text}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mylipsum}{just dummy text}
\newcommand{\Mylipsum}{\mylipsum{} \mylipsum}

\begin{document}
\mylipsum

\Mylipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

With some help from `xparse` we can extract a rich supply of sentences from `lipsum`; precisely 1498, I guess they're sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

% store a big set of sentences
\unpacklipsum[1-100] % it was \UnpackLipsum before version 2.0

\ExplSyntaxOn
% unpack \lipsumexp
\seq_new:N \g_lipsum_sentences_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\seq_gset_split:NnV \g_lipsum_sentences_seq {.~} \lipsumexp

\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentence}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}O{1-7}}
 {
  \lipsumsentenceaux #1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentenceaux}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { #1 }.~
   }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { ##1 }.~
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Seven sentences}

\lipsumsentence

\section{Three sentences}

\lipsumsentence[2-4]

\section{Some single sentences}

\lipsumsentence[1]

\lipsumsentence[2]

\lipsumsentence[3]

\lipsumsentence[4]

\lipsumsentence[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code no longer compiles because `\UnpackLipsum` has been [deprecated](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/lipsum/lipsum.pdf).

Answer (score 11):

```
\newcount\zz
\loop
Hello world.
\advance\zz1
\ifnum\zz<10
\repeat
```

writes Hello world 10 times.

Answer (score 10):

Starting from version 2.0 on, the `lipsum` package provides a second optional parameter to the `\lipsum` command which selects a range of single sentences from the paragraphs selected by the first optional parameter. The syntax is

```
\lipsum[<paragraph range>][<sentence range>]
```

where each `<range>` can be a single number `n` or a range `n-m`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1]\par
\lipsum[1][2]\par
\lipsum[1][3]\par
\lipsum[1][4-6]\par
\lipsum[2-4][12-18]
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: How to make sure I have lipsum 2.0? The previous examples don't work for me, so I suspect I have the old version of lipsum

Comment: When I use this \lipsum[1][1] I get Illegal Unit of Measure (pt inserted).

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a macro for the dummy text and a loop to repeat it, taking as an argument the number of repetitions. These commands work in any variety of TeX, but I illustrate their use in a LaTeX document.

```
\documentclass{article} 

% Define the dummy sentence, an ancient palindrome.
\def\sator{Sator Arepo tenet opera rotas.}

% Create a command to print the sentence repeatedly.
% Argument #1 is the number of times to repeat it.
\newcount\loopcounter
\def\dummysentences#1{%
    \loopcounter = #1
    \loop
        \sator\ %
        \advance\loopcounter by -1
        \ifnum\loopcounter > 0
    \repeat%
}

\begin{document}

\sator

\dummysentences{5}

\begin{itemize}
\item \sator
\item \dummysentences{3}
\item \dummysentences{2}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See also my answer here: [Is there a dummy package like Lipsum or Blindtext for Tables and Figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202739/is-there-a-dummy-package-like-lipsum-or-blindtext-for-tables-and-figures/208857#208857)

Comment: ... and of course: `\def\sator{\noindent\ttfamily sator\\ arepo\\ tenet\\ opera\\ rotas}`.

Comment: @jon See the command `\satorfig` from the package in the answer I link to. :)