# Obtaining lorum ipsum text

Tags: lipsum

Many questions use lorem ipsum filler text from package lipsum. I am testing a regex script on text files nested within different folders. For this and to improve LaTeX understanding better I would like to output lipsum text into a plain text file.

A manual way is to run a LaTeX engine (say pdflatex), open the pdf and copy and paste into a plain text document. The \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} line have added to aid copying, but am unsure if this makes a difference to the lorem ipsum text.

Here are two ideas, but I do not know if these are feasible methods nor how to implement them if they are.

1. Use pdflatex (or other command) flags.
2. Use TeX command line tools to identify the file location within the lipsum package where the lorem ipsum text is located.

From these the lorum ipsum text could be obtained and redirected to a text file.

The functionality to vary the amount of lorum ipsum text may also be helpful, for example if output to three files they could each have a different amount of filler text. This would rule out 2. above.

The accepted answer here [Is it possible to generate a set amount of words using lipsum?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462453/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-set-amount-of-words-using-lipsum?r=SearchResults) says “the output of \lipsum is protected, so the only way get the text is to copy it from a previous PDF”. An explanation of this is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\unpacklipsum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newwrite\lipsum
\immediate\openout\lipsum=\jobname.txt

\unpacklipsum[1]
\immediate\write\lipsum{\lipsumexp}

\stop
```

The generated file will be

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
```

Comment: This works well. The \immediate is necessary as otherwise there is not any output. How to know that \immediate is necessary in this situation?

Comment: @SingleMalt By default `\write` operations are delayed at the next shipout (when a page is being completed and written out to the PDF file) because the main usage is for producing tables of contents or cross-references and the page number cannot be known when the `\write` instruction occurs. When no such detail is necessary, one generally uses `\immediate`. In this case it's mandatory, because the LaTeX run is not supposed to produce any printable output.

Answer (score 1):

The text is in the file `lipsum-ltd.tex` with the minimal amount of tex markup which you can easily strip using command line tools, or any text editor.

For example

```
sed -e 's/[\\{}%].*//' `kpsewhich lipsum.ltd.tex`
```

locates the file and removes the commands and comments resulting in

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant
morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus
vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor
gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh
mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci
sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.


Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan
bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi
ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante.
Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla
ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

....
```

Comment: Elegant solution. There are multiple words of "sed" in the output of lorem ipsum. Does "ltd" have any meaning in the filename lipsum.ltd.tex?

Comment: @SingleMalt lipsum doc says it stands for lipsum text definition