wrapfigure overlapping fcolorbox
I'm using wrapfigure together with fcolorbox, but it seems the figure overlaps the colorbox, as shown in the image below.

Is it possible for the wrapfigure not to overlap with the fcolorbox?

It looks like there is quite some white space between the main text and the wrapfigure's caption: at least two sentences from the main text could still fit below the caption. Is it possible to modify this?



MWE:
\RequirePackage{etex}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\linespread{1} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}

\setlength {\marginparwidth }{12mm}

\usepackage{dashrule}

\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\newcommand{\secshort}{\S}

\usepackage{caption}

 %To have 8 pt caption names and texts:
\makeatletter
\newcommand\eightpt{\@setfontsize\eightpt{8}{8}}
\makeatother
\DeclareCaptionFont{eightpt}{\eightpt}
\captionsetup{font=eightpt,skip=0pt}  % I added skip=0pt to reduce space between caption and fig.

\usepackage[left=15mm,
right=15mm,
top=15mm,
bottom=15mm,includehead,includefoot, headsep=0.7em, footskip=0.7em]
{geometry}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{enumitem}


\headheight=14pt

\hyphenation{in-fra-struc-tu-res}

% To reduce spacing above \paragraph
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{0.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%% For the purpuse of this MWE, 
%%% this whole section is to enable lipsum sentences: 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Taken from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254906/50467
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Store a big set of sentences
\unpacklipsum[1-100] % it was \UnpackLipsum before version 2.0

\ExplSyntaxOn
% unpack \lipsumexp
\seq_new:N \g_lipsum_sentences_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\seq_gset_split:NnV \g_lipsum_sentences_seq {.~} \lipsumexp

\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentence}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}O{1-7}}
 {
  \lipsumsentenceaux #1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentenceaux}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { #1 }.~
   }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { ##1 }.~
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \myparagraph to enable new line after \paragraph:
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}


\begin{document}

\myparagraph{ \emph{B) An important thought}}
\textbullet \textbf{ \lipsumsentence[1]}

\lipsumsentence[1-5]

\lipsumsentence[6]

\lipsumsentence[7-25]

\lipsumsentence[26-30]


\vspace{0.2em}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{center}
  \caption{\lipsumsentence[1-2]} 
  \label{fig}
\end{wrapfigure}


\noindent
{\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}
\hspace{-0.5mm}\fcolorbox{black}{gray!15}{\parbox{0.985\textwidth}{
\textbf{Important:}
\lipsumsentence[31-42]
}}}\\


\myparagraph{ \emph{C) Another important thought}}
\textbullet \textbf{ \lipsumsentence[31]}
\lipsumsentence[39-35]

\lipsumsentence[46]

\lipsumsentence[47-67]

\lipsumsentence[68-87]
\vspace{0.2em}

\noindent
{\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}
\hspace{-0.5mm}\fcolorbox{black}{gray!15}{\parbox{0.985\textwidth}{
\textbf{Important}
\lipsumsentence[80-87]
}}}\\

\end{document}




unrelated but don't do \RequirePackage{etex} unless you have very specific legacy requirements in very old documents, it breaks many features of latex. Actually you have \usepackage{fontspec} so this is luatex or xetex, so simpler; don't use etex you can't have a document needing etex package compatibility that works with a unicode tex.

It's not clear what you want to happen. wrapfig adjusts the paragraph parameters for line breaking so tex tries to break lines leaving space but you have \fcolorbox{black}{gray!15}{\parbox{0.985\textwidth} so (once you add in the box padding, that's a full width box and will not change its size whatever the target line width, just as, without wrapfig, if you use \parbox{2\textwidth}{...} it will be too wide whatever the current width specifed

\noindent {\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}  adds a word space at the start of the line coming from the newline in the source, that is partially compensated by the following negative hspace but it would be better not to add the space, comment out the end of line

just move the wrapfig after the box so the following text wraps around it?

@DavidCarlisle Many thanks for your comments, I learned a lot. Thanks for pointing out comment No. 1. Comment No. 4 did remove the overlapping, thanks.
Regarding comment No. 3, I can see the compensation of spacings. I'm not sure what "comment out the end of the line" would mean here. Do you mean adding a % at the end of the mentioned line, i.e. \noindent {\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}% ? Thanks again.

yes % as you show,

wrapfigure won't make your \fcolorbox narrower. You need to.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  left=15mm,
  right=15mm,
  top=15mm,
  bottom=15mm,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  headsep=0.7em,
  footskip=0.7em,
  headheight=14pt,
  marginparwidth=12mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

 %To have 8 pt caption names and texts:
\newcommand\eightpt{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont}
\DeclareCaptionFont{eightpt}{\eightpt}
\captionsetup{font=eightpt,skip=0pt}

\hyphenation{in-fra-struc-tu-res}

% To reduce spacing above \paragraph
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{0.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%% For the purpuse of this MWE, 
%%% this whole section is to enable lipsum sentences: 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Taken from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254906/50467
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Store a big set of sentences
\unpacklipsum[1-100] % it was \UnpackLipsum before version 2.0

\ExplSyntaxOn
% unpack \lipsumexp
\seq_new:N \g_lipsum_sentences_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\seq_gset_split:NnV \g_lipsum_sentences_seq {.~} \lipsumexp

\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentence}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}O{1-7}}
 {
  \lipsumsentenceaux #1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentenceaux}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { #1 }.~
   }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { ##1 }.~
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \myparagraph to enable new line after \paragraph:
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

\newcommand{\important}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \par\addvspace{0.2em}\noindent
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2pt}%
  \fcolorbox{black}{gray!15}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimeval{#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}{\textbf{Important:} #2}%
  }%
  \endgroup
  \par\addvspace{0.2em}%
}

\begin{document}

\myparagraph{\emph{B) An important thought}}
\textbullet\ \textbf{\lipsumsentence[1]}

\lipsumsentence[1-5]

\lipsumsentence[6]

\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\lipsumsentence[1-2]} 
\label{fig}
\end{wrapfigure}

\important[0.5\textwidth-\intextsep]{\lipsumsentence[31-42]}


\myparagraph{\emph{C) Another important thought}}
\textbullet\ \textbf{\lipsumsentence[31]}
\lipsumsentence[39-35]

\lipsumsentence[46]

\lipsumsentence[47-67]

\lipsumsentence[68-87]

\important{\lipsumsentence[80-87]}

\end{document}

Make a favor to yourself and define commands or environments for complex things that appear more than once. In this case, I define \important to have an optional argument which represents the desired width, to which we subtract twice \fboxrule and twice \fboxsep in order to get the proper size for the \parbox. The \parbox is top aligned, so it will play well with wrapfig.
In the case at hand, the width should be 0.5\textwidth minus \intextsep. However, the \important{...} part will count as a single line, as far as erapfig is concerned, so you have to help it computing “by sight” the exact number of lines to span.
A few points to note:

DON'T load etex.

I removed several packages that aren't involved in the example.

Avoid intermixing package loading and settings.

headheight and marginparwidth should be set with geometry.

\fontsize{8}{8} is a bad choice: the baseline skip should always be greater than the font size.




Many thanks for all these comments. I really learned a lot. Thanks a lot for pointing out 1.,  and for 3. and  4.  (e.g., I learned those settings had to be indeed in geometry, my bad), thanks for pointing out that \fontsize{8}{8} is indeed a bad choice, and for the brilliant \important environment, where one, by tweaking the 0.5 value inside the square brackets, can indeed adjust how wide the box spans the page.
