wrapfigure inside longtblr environment (tabularrary)
I am attempting to use wrapfigure inside a longtblr environment, but it doesn't seem to work as expected: code in MWE1 below, which produces the following output:

As an alternative, I tried using minipage, but this approach leaves a noticeable white space (labeled as "1" in the image, and code in MWE2 below):

How could I properly embed this figure into the table text?
MWE1 (compiling with LuaLaTeX 2024 in Overleaf):
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  left=15mm,
  right=15mm,
  top=15mm,
  bottom=15mm,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  headsep=0.7em,
  footskip=0.7em,
  headheight=14pt,
  marginparwidth=12mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% For the purpuse of this MWE, 
%%% this whole section is to enable lipsum sentences: 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Obtained from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254906/50467
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Store a big set of sentences
\unpacklipsum[1-100] % it was \UnpackLipsum before version 2.0

\ExplSyntaxOn
% unpack \lipsumexp
\seq_new:N \g_lipsum_sentences_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\seq_gset_split:NnV \g_lipsum_sentences_seq {.~} \lipsumexp

\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentence}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}O{1-7}}
 {
  \lipsumsentenceaux #1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentenceaux}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { #1 }.~
   }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { ##1 }.~
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  label = none,
  entry = none,
]{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {Q[131]Q[813]},
  cell{1}{1} = {c=2}{0.944\linewidth},
  cell{2}{1} = {c=2}{0.944\linewidth},
  hlines,
  vlines,
}
\textbf{Some title} & \\
{\textbf{Other title}
} & \\
\textbf{\lipsumsentence[1]} & 
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
% \begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
% \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
% \end{minipage}
\lipsumsentence[1-5]
\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}

MWE2 (compiling with LuaLaTeX 2024 in Overleaf):
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  left=15mm,
  right=15mm,
  top=15mm,
  bottom=15mm,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  headsep=0.7em,
  footskip=0.7em,
  headheight=14pt,
  marginparwidth=12mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% For the purpuse of this MWE, 
%%% this whole section is to enable lipsum sentences: 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Obtained from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254906/50467
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Store a big set of sentences
\unpacklipsum[1-100] % it was \UnpackLipsum before version 2.0

\ExplSyntaxOn
% unpack \lipsumexp
\seq_new:N \g_lipsum_sentences_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\seq_gset_split:NnV \g_lipsum_sentences_seq {.~} \lipsumexp

\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentence}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}O{1-7}}
 {
  \lipsumsentenceaux #1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentenceaux}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { #1 }.~
   }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { ##1 }.~
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  label = none,
  entry = none,
]{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {Q[131]Q[813]},
  cell{1}{1} = {c=2}{0.944\linewidth},
  cell{2}{1} = {c=2}{0.944\linewidth},
  hlines,
  vlines,
}
\textbf{Some title} & \\
{\textbf{Other title}
} & \\
\textbf{\lipsumsentence[1]} & 
% \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
%    \centering
%     \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
% \end{wrapfigure}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\lipsumsentence[1-5]
\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


you can simply use wrapfig, I would expect.

Your question is a bit confusing. You talk about longtable, but in your code, you use longtblr from a completely different package.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, and my apologies for the confusion. If I'm not mistaken longtblr belongs to tabularray package. Edited post and tags to avoid confusion.

You still mention longtable several times in the body of your question

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, and my apologies again, I overlooked those instances in the text as well

@DavidC. Much less confusing! Thanks for the update!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Many thanks to you for reviewing (Do you think there is something still ambiguous in the post?) Do you have any ideas to solve this?

@DavidC. You could increase your chances for an answer by only asking about one problem in a post and providing an actual MWE.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, I did my best to rewrite the post now

You could use the wrapstuff package like this:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapstuff}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{
  colspec = {Q[2cm,font=\bfseries,halign=l,valign=h]X[valign=h]},
  cell{1,2}{1} = {c=2}{},
  hlines,
  vlines,
}
Some title & \\
Other title & \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. &
\begin{wrapstuff}[width=0.25\linewidth,l]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapstuff}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\lipsum[2]\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}



Thanks so much! :) It looks like this package solves all these issues, it's awesome :)

@DavidC. You're welcome!
