# Remove "belowskip" only for tables

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, captions

In a twosided `scrbook`, I am aligning all my figures and tables on top of the page (via `[!t]`). As a result, the upper edge of the figures is higher than the upper edge of the table caption.
This can be seen in the image below which I took from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202739/is-there-a-dummy-package-like-lipsum-or-blindtext-for-tables-and-figures)

My editor asks me to change this so that all pages start at the same height. As far as I understand, the space between captions and text is adjusted with `belowskip` -- but that would change it for both figures (space below the caption) and tables (space above the caption).
**So can I adjust the space above table captions only?**

[image]

Comment: it would help a lot to have an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrbook` is a **KOMA-Script class**, so you can use option `captions=tableheading`:

```
\documentclass[
  captions=tableheading
  ]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\Blindtext

\begin{table}[!t]
\centering
\caption{A table caption}
\rule{5cm}{1cm}
\end{table}

\Blindtext

\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\rule{5cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With a **standard class** you can load package `caption` with option `tableposition=top`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\Blindtext

\begin{table}[!t]
\centering
\caption{A table caption}
\rule{5cm}{1cm}
\end{table}

\Blindtext

\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\rule{5cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]