# Table caption on top of page - remove vertical space

Tags: tables, captions, koma-script

I guess my problem is related to the caption.
When a table (with the caption on top) appears on top of a page, there is always sone vertical whitespace before. Figure however (caption below) align with the top perfectly. I guess this is because of the caption? Can I somehow globally remove this whitespace? Caption offers some option to tell it whether the caption is on top or bottom, but this doesn't help...
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
pdftex,
a4paper,
parskip=half,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \caption\textbf{Fancy table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        This is & a fancy & table \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\Blindtext[5]{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also related: [Remove “belowskip” only for tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317996/remove-belowskip-only-for-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell KOMA-Script, that you want table headings instead of table signatures:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
parskip=half,
captions=tableheading% formatting for table headings (see the KOMA-Script manual)
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setkomafont{caption}{\bfseries}% caption text (but not label) bf (see the KOMA-Script manual)

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Fancy table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        This is & a fancy & table \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\Blindtext[5]{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, `\caption` has a mandatory argument!

Note also that you should not use `\textbf` to make the table title bold, but use `\setkomafont{caption}{…}` to change the font of the caption text (and optionally also `\setkomafont{captionlabel}{…}` for the label of the caption text.

Comment: Thanks, the KOMA option helped. The \textbf and the madatory option, I am aware of. It was just some copy&paste error for the MWE.

Answer (score 0):

There are two lengths: `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`. Usually caption is put below the figure/table, so `\abovecaptionskip` has some non zero value and `belowcaptionskip` is equal to zero. You should not change this values globally -- they are used both for figures and tables.

I suggest to use the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package and define two different setups: one for tables and default for figures. For example:

```
\captionsetup[table]{position=above, aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=10pt}
```

BTW It is a really usefull package.

Comment: Package `caption` is useful in several cases, but if you use a KOMA-Script class, you don't need package `caption` to solve this problem.